# Will ranking "correlation" of variables by Pearson's return the same results as chi-square and F stats?

Tags: correlation, anova, chi-squared-test, pearson-r, f-statistic

Generally speaking my understanding and experience is that when I have some target variable and want to see which other variables best correlate with it (for instance to build a predictive model), ranking by the absolute value of a correlation coefficient and the test value from a statistical test produce pretty same-ish results.

For instance:

- Continue variables with a dichotomous target - ranking by either the absolute value of the point biserial coefficient OR the F stat from ANOVA
- Dichotomous variable with a dichotomous target - ranking by either the absolute value of the phi coefficient or the chi-square from a chi-square test

Do these methods indeed produce generally equivalent rankings? If not, can we build some intuition on why not and when they tend diverge?

Comment: Are you assuming that all computations are done on the same data, i.e., same number of observations (particularly no missing values that appear in some but not all variables)?

Comment: what is phi coeficient?

Comment: @Lewian
Right, controlling for the dataset. Any missing values have already been handled by some kind of imputation (or dropped).

Comment: In general your answer will depend on what specific test you are using. For example, here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient you can find a test statistic $t$ that is a monotonic function of the point biserial correlation (also in absolute value), meaning that the ranking will be the same regardless of whether you use the correlation or $|t|$. In general one could look at the definitions and see whether there's a monotonic relation between the two.

Comment: @Lewian That's not quite what I meant. I mean comparing the similar-case test of significance (i.e. chi-square) vs a measure of correlation (i.e. phi coefficient), not say phi vs the some p-value for phi (though if you tell me that finding a p-value for phi would essentially be going through the route of chi-square, I wouldn't be surprised).

Comment: The question seems unclear, or at least imprecise. The correlation coefficient is entirely dependent on your data, one can calculate it blindly. A test statistic is however computed from the test procedure, which one has to define. So, even if there might be similarities, could you better define what you mean? And in addition, what do you mean by "equivalent rankings"? The entities are entirely different, so it's unclear how any kind of equivalence could exist.

Comment: As a sidenote, would not recommend basing your variable selection on bivariate correlations for a predictive model, nor any other automated method that capitalizes on chance (see Frank Harrell's 'Regression Modeling Strategies' for alternatives involving domain knowledge and bootstrapping, for example).

Comment: @cherub Perhaps I should I said the "corresponding test of significance" vs correlation. I've given a couple of explicit definitions above (for instance chisquare versus phi (for instance in the situation of two binary variables). For the rankings side of it, imagine the need of plucking out the best features to use for a prediction problem from a large pool. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Kuku Perhaps, but in practice one is oft forced to do such when there are a large number of variables or if a part of the selection needs to be built into, say, a validation fold.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. By "producing equivalent rankings" is meant, that the same order of variables is produced as in ordering them in (actually absolute) size of correlation? And do you want to compare only the methods you describe, or even more general? In general the observation seems intuitive. But if one of the methods has the same level of 'approachability' is an entirely different question; and the means to compare the level of agreement seems a bit random.

Comment: @cherub Say you want to build a predictive model and you need to automate a part of feature selection. To do so you'll want to rank them by something *like* how well they correlate with the target and pick the top k. One could rank by correlation coefficients, or one could rank by the results of significance test (for instance on a means difference between two groups). What I'm saying is generally I find I get similar results and exploring that notion.

Comment: @Josh : ack'. I don't think that there is anything wrong by going with that notion. The observation doesn't seem far fetched. But technically correlation and the outcome of whatever test and a test statistic are entirely different "objects", for the lack of a better word. This is why I fail to see a connection. Even if there might be "sufficiently similar" rankings, I'd still think it would be non trivial to formalise this. The correlation coefficient depends on the data, while the rankings of any test depend on a model and the procedure; which are not "trivial" math expressions.

Comment: @cherub I definitely agree! I think understanding when these two (indeed disparate in intention and methods) calculations will tend converge and diverge to the same results is interesting and helpful.